# Como fazer botões de vários formatos em java?

Tags: java, swing

Estou criando um joguinho usando Swing, e gostaria de fazer botões com formatos diferenciados, do jeito que eu escolher. Por exemplo: um botão redondo, ou um botão em forma de olho, por exemplo.

E se souberem, eu gostaria também de saber como colocar texturas nesses botões.

Comment: Você está usando Swing? é uma aplicação de desktop?

Comment: Sim, estou na biblioteca swing, é para desktop normalmente, um joguinho!

Comment: @IsaacReinaldo adicionei um link na minha resposta para o projeto completo no GitHub, caso tenha tido dificuldades para rodar o código, agora ficou mais fácil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie uma JLabel e coloque a uma imagem a seu gosto, na textura que desejar e no formato que desejar. Para simular o efeito de um botão sobrescreva os métodos de `mousePressed()`, `mouseReleased()` e `mouseMoved()`.

Ao passar o mouse sobre a imagem deve-se verificar se o ponto atual é transparente ou não, para não trocar a imagem erroneamente, já que sua JLabel continua sendo um retângulo entretanto a imagem não. Também deve-se verificar no momento do clique do mouse, para não permitir que a JLabel seja clicada se o mouse estiver sobre uma área transparente da imagem.

Para simular corretamente o comportamento de um botão você deverá criar uma imagem para cada um dos estado: `imagem normal`, `imagem clicada` e `imagem com o mouse em cima`.

Seguem exemplos que eu criei:

**pawn(regular).png**

[image: pawn(regular).png]

**pawn(hovering).png**

[image: pawn(hovering).png]

**pawn(clicking).png**

[image: pawn(clicking).png]

Coloque o seguinte código dentro do seu construtor para implementar exatamente o algoritmo que eu escrevi acima:

```
final ImageIcon regular = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("pawn(regular).png"));
final ImageIcon hovering = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("pawn(hovering).png"));
final ImageIcon clicking = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("pawn(clicking).png"));
final BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("pawn(regular).png"));

final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(regular);
lblNewLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int pixel = img.getRGB(e.getPoint().x, e.getPoint().y);
        if( (pixel>>24) == 0x00 ) {
            return;
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("I was clicked! I really look like a button.");
            lblNewLabel.setIcon(clicking);
        }
        super.mousePressed(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        int pixel = img.getRGB(e.getPoint().x, e.getPoint().y);
        if( (pixel>>24) == 0x00 ) {
            lblNewLabel.setIcon(regular);
        }
        else {
            lblNewLabel.setIcon(hovering);                  
        }
        super.mouseReleased(e);
    }
});
lblNewLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        int pixel = img.getRGB(e.getPoint().x, e.getPoint().y);
        if( (pixel>>24) == 0x00 ) {
            lblNewLabel.setIcon(regular);
            lblNewLabel.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
        else {
            lblNewLabel.setIcon(hovering);
            lblNewLabel.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
        super.mouseMoved(e);
    }
});
contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
```

Para deixar mais legal eu mudei o cursor para mãozinha quando estiver por cima de uma área não transparente da JLabel.

Criei recentemente um repositório para disponibilizar o [projeto completo no meu GitHub](https://github.com/matheuscs/CustomSwingButton), basta baixá-lo e importar no Eclipse. Todas as imagens já estão no repositório para facilitar.

Answer (score 2):

Na minha opinião, você está pedindo três perguntas diferentes. Eu vou responder somente um deles.

**Botão redondo**

A classe `Border` em Swing oferece da possibilidade de usar um rádio:

```
private static class RoundedBorder implements Border {

    private int radius;

    RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
    }


    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }


    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x,y,width-1,height-1,radius,radius);
    }
}
```

Depois, tudo que você tem que fazer é estabelecer essa classe para o botão:

```
jButton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(50));
```

Resultados:

[image: screenshoot]

---

Fonte: [SO, por Lalchand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634480/1505348).