# Criar botão com icone java?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Estou com dificuldades em criar um botão com icone no java, já olhei varios tutorias, mas não conseguir fazer funcionar.

Obs: estou usando eclipse, Windows 10. A pasta que está a imagem é src onde está o arquivo da classe Main.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            Icon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("flag.png");
            frame.add(new JButton("Flag",imageIcon));

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(300,400);
            frame.setVisible(true);

       }
   }
```

Comment: Algo assim? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15490/3117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente, funciona tendo a imagem na mesma pasta que o arquivo compilado (**.class**). Eu testei seu código 
com uma imagem qualquer e funcionou perfeitamente (compilando "na mão"). Mas, fazendo deste jeito, a imagem não vai fazer parte do **.jar** gerado, só serve pra testes mesmo.

O recomendado é colocar suas imagens na pasta `Resources/Images` e modificar o código para algo como:

```
Icon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/flag.png"));
```